# Select2.js v4.0: How transmit filter text to ajax source data?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using the very excinting library select2.js **in version 4.0**

I can display a dropdown from dynamic ajax Data but the enhanced dropdowns produced by dropdown2  allow to user to enter a filter text and I want to send this text to the server methode as a parameter for filtering data returning by ajax .

I am trying with a asp mvc project

javascript code:

```
$(".example-select2").select2({
    ajax: {
        dataType: 'json',
         url: '@Url.Action("GetSrcMethode", "GetCheckSet")',
       processResults: function (data) 
       {
             return {results: JSON.parse(data)};
       } 
      //what I am looking for
      //javascript code for sending search as parameter            
    }
});
```

My C# methode is

```
public JsonResult GetSrcMethode(string searchTerme //!!!always null!!!)
    {            
        //...
        // get data and filter it from searchTerme
        //...
        Object json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filteredData);
        return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Parameter received in searchTerme variable is always null.

Do you know how can I transmit search text of the dropdown in parameter to the server methode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Select2 sends the search term as the `q` query parameter. So the url that is generated for AJAX requests is `/url/?q=search+terms`. In your case, you should be able to change the parameter for your method to be named `q`, and then you can use that as the incoming search term when filtering.

```
public JsonResult GetSrcMethode(string q)
    {            
        //...
        // get data and filter it from q
        //...
        Object json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filteredData);
        return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Alternatively, you can change the `ajax.data` option (which is translated into query parameters) to return an object with a key matching the parameter you are looking for.